# Script that changes ip for remote server

Tags: powershell, network-programming, system-administration

I need a powershell script thats changes a remote server to specific ip address and gateway
I found some scripts online but the problem is that i have to specify the old ip address,
but i want the script to be as simple as possible just run and problem solved!
so for example i tryed:

```
$oldip = nslookup $servername
```

**it prints the whole command, is there a way to get just the ip output and change to a new ip address?**

Comment: You can just use ping.exe, or the more native cmdlets from powershell such as `Test-Connection` to return an object you can work with easier. As far as changing the IP Address, this is definitely possible. Would like to see what you have tried so far, even if you aren't good at Powershell, you should be able to come up with something yourself we can help with.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine something like this:

```
$someRemotePc = "localhost" #replace 
$someRemotePcIPoriginal = test-connection -count 1 -ComputerName $someRemotePc
$someRemotePcFriendlyIp = $someRemotePcIPoriginal.IPV4Address.IPAddressToString


"the IP addres of $someRemotePc was $someRemotePcFriendlyIp"

#change IP here
#some command....

#make Results
@{
  ComputerName = $someRemotePc;
  Ip_Orig = $someRemotePcFriendlyIp;
  Ip_New  = #LogicToGetNewIp
}
```